# C# find panels adjecent to panel being clicked

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a little game where you turn all panels green.
I do this by getting a 5x5 grid of panels, every panel has a 1/3 chance to be green, otherwise it will start as red.
my problem is that i do not have the slightest clue how to start the main problem.
when i click a panel, the panel above, left ,right and below need to change color aswell.
at the moment i do not know how to identify which panels are next to the one being clicked.

this is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Panel[,] PanelArray = new Panel[5,5];
    Random R = new Random();
    int R1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
            {
                R1 = R.Next(0, 3);

                PanelArray[r, c] = new Panel
                {
                    Size = new Size(50, 50),
                    Location = new Point(PanelContainer.Width / 5 * c, PanelContainer.Height / 5 * r),
                    BackColor = Color.Red,
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
                };
                PanelArray[r, c].Click += new EventHandler(PanelArray_Click);
                if (R1 == 1) PanelArray[r, c].BackColor = Color.Green;
                PanelContainer.Controls.Add(PanelArray[r, c]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PanelArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel P = (Panel)sender;

        if (P.BackColor == Color.Red) P.BackColor = Color.Green;
        else if (P.BackColor == Color.Green) P.BackColor = Color.Red;

        if (CheckWin()) MessageBox.Show("test");
    }

    private bool CheckWin()
    {
        //foreach panel green blah blah
        return false;
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Use two nested for-loops to find the panel back in the PanelArray, gives you the row and column.

Comment: Please, use a proper punctuation in you question description to make it more readable for the community.

Comment: Or you can use the `Tag` property in your `Panel` objects to store the indexes. f.e.: store as a `string` ("x,y"), and you can parse this.

Comment: I would create a class that contains a `Panel` as well as any panels that are next to that panel. When you click a `Panel`, that `Panel`'s click event should call a method in the class to turn any adjacent panels green.

Comment: Why not put your panels in a 5x5 TableLayoutPanel? Then getting the adjacent panels is very simple, since you what position in the TableLayoutPanel each of your panels is at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.8) property in your `Panel` objects to store some information.

```
PanelArray[r, c] = new Panel
{
    Size = new Size(50, 50),
    Location = new Point(PanelContainer.Width / 5 * c, PanelContainer.Height / 5 * r),
    BackColor = Color.Red,
    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
    Tag = (Row: r, Column: c)
};
```

In your `PanelArray_Click` method, you can get the indexes:

```
var indexes = ((int Row, int Column))P.Tag;
var row = indexes.Row;
var column = indexes.Column;
// Todo: your logic here
```

In the `Tag` property, you can store any object, so you can create some class to store data, if you need.

Other solution is two for loops, to get the indexes, like:

```
private (int Row, int Column) GetIndexes(Panel panel)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < PanelArray.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < PanelArray.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            if (PanelArray[x, y] == panel)
            {
                return (x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Not found.");
}
```

And then you can use in your `PanelArray_Click` method:

```
var indexes = this.GetIndexes(P);
var row = indexes.Row;
var column = indexes.Column;
// Todo: your logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is easy trick to get row and column.  Create a class that inherits the Panel and adds a row and column.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MyPanel[,] PanelArray = new MyPanel[5, 5];
        Random R = new Random();
        int R1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                {
                    R1 = R.Next(0, 3);

                    PanelArray[r, c] = new MyPanel
                    {
                        Size = new Size(50, 50),
                        Location = new Point(PanelContainer.Width / 5 * c, PanelContainer.Height / 5 * r),
                        BackColor = Color.Red,
                        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
                        row = r,
                        col = c
                    };
                    PanelArray[r, c].Click += new EventHandler(PanelArray_Click);
                    if (R1 == 1) PanelArray[r, c].BackColor = Color.Green;
                    PanelContainer.Controls.Add(PanelArray[r, c]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void PanelArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyPanel P = sender as MyPanel;
            int row = P.row;
            int col = P.col;

            if (P.BackColor == Color.Red) P.BackColor = Color.Green;
            else if (P.BackColor == Color.Green) P.BackColor = Color.Red;

            if (CheckWin()) MessageBox.Show("test");
        }

        private bool CheckWin()
        {
            //foreach panel green blah blah
            return false;
        }
    }
    public class MyPanel : Panel
    {
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int col { get; set; }
    }
}
```